# Change to react useState causes redux useSelector to fail

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have just started to create a react FC and using latest redux but have run in to some issues. Probably I am missing something. But there is not much code yet so I most be doing something wrong.

Below code snippet works on first render and firing methods etc.
But as soon as I update the react state for example use `setShowToaster` I get three of this error:

[image]

If I use devtool(F12) and change the state manually on `showToaster` through the reactComponents extension for chrome it also fails.

I have tried to remove everything until I have only these left:
`const {} = useSelector((state) => state.overview);` and `const [showToaster, setShowToaster] = useState(false);` Then I open devtools and manually change the state and it fails.

If I remove `useSelector` everything work and I can use `setShowToaster` without any problems.

```
const {
    isLoadingComments,
    comments,
    error,
} = useSelector((state) => state.overview);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
        dispatch(getCommentsData());
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);

const [showToaster, setShowToaster] = useState(false);
```

I have tried to debug inside the react-dom method `areHookInputsEqual` and the if-statement that fails, `if (nextDeps.length !== prevDeps.length)` but don't get much wiser on that.

[image]

Any sugestions or fingers to point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**
I aslo have some really strange behavior with the devtools on this page:
https://gyazo.com/2e400be89699c2c5e5759132ba279d1f

These are the states I change in the clip, and when I change the top state that's when I get above error.

```
    const [showToaster, setShowToaster] = useState(false);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
    const [isDispatchSuccess, setIsSuccess] = useState(false);
```

Comment: That seems extremely strange. What versions of React and React-Redux are you using? Can you put together a CodeSandbox that shows this happening?

Comment: Im using latest, redux: 4.2.0, rkt:1.8.5, react/react-dom: 18.2.0. Sure can create a sandbox.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-jones-hihfbz?file=/src/Overview.jsx

Comment: I forgot to mention that my first fault was what is happening in this sandbox: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. From there I tested like described above

Comment: I fixed my issue after reading the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html. Moved all useState to the top and nothing breaks anymore